Can't access protected property of abstract class from child
I can't access service property of Abstract class from Concrete class using super call, it just works with this. But when I use super, typescript doesn't show any type errors
interface Service {
  do(): void;
}

abstract class Abstract {
  constructor(protected readonly service: Service) {}

  abstract execute(): void;
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  constructor(service: Service) {
    super(service);
  }

  execute(): void {
    super.service.do(); // <- if i replace "super" with "this", it works
  }
}

class ServiceImpl implements Service {
  do(): void {
    console.log("i saved something");
  }
}

const concrete = new Concrete(new ServiceImpl());

console.log(concrete.execute()); // <- it will throw error

this code will throw
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'do')
I tried calling service with super to improve my code readability, so others could easily identify service as a protected member of Abstract class. As Typescript recognised service from super call, by the type checker, i expected it would work, but it doesn't

Don't use super, use this. There should be a TS error; the fact that there isn't one is a known bug (see ms/TS#42214. super.service tries to access the service property of Abstract.prototype, which doesn't exist. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Yes, you can write an answer. it fully addresses my question

@DaviBanfiNogueira please look at my answer, I tried to describe the answer with links to the language documentation.

The super keyword lets you access properties of the prototype of the class. It does not access some hypothetical instance of the superclass (there is no such instance; the field from the superclass is overwritten by the field of the subclass).  So if the class member you're referring to is bound to the class instance, then it will be undefined when you access it on super.  If you want to access an instance field, you should use this instead of super.
This doesn't have much to do with protected or abstract classes or properties. You can indeed access methods or accessor properties (those using get) with super, since those do appear on the prototype:
class Parent {
  constructor() { }
  method() {
    console.log("Parent");
  }
  get accessor() {
    return "Parent";
  }
  prop = "Parent";
}

class Child extends Parent {
  method() {
    console.log("Child");
  }
  get accessor() {
    return "Child";
  }
  prop = "Child;"

  execute(): void {
    this.method(); // "Child"
    super.method(); // "Parent"
    console.log(this.accessor); // "Child"
    console.log(super.accessor); // "Parent"
    console.log(this.prop); // "Child"
    console.log(super.prop); // undefined
  }
}


So then the real issue you're facing is that your code does not produce a TypeScript error, even though you are accessing an impossible super field.  This is apparently a known bug, as reported in microsoft/TypeScript#42214. It looks like TypeScript cannot determine that your service is a field, because it is a parameter property, and thus does not complain. If you rewrite the code to not use parameter properties: you get the expected error:
abstract class Abstract {
  protected readonly service: Service; // explicitly declare
  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.service = service; // assign
  }
  abstract execute(): void;
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  constructor(service: Service) {
    super(service);
  }

  execute(): void {
    super.service.do(); // error!
  }
}

Playground link to code

The link “The super keyword” leads to javascript documentation, not typescript.

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. The super keyword documentation for JS explains how it works in TS as well.

The TypeScript documentation says otherwise, as I showed in my answer.

Could you spell out the disparity? The JS documentation says that you cannot access “super fields” because they are not on the prototype. I’m aware that the TS handbook has its own section on  classes, but if you see something there that disagrees with the JS documentation, I’d be interested in knowing it.

The doc I linked to says "Note that instance fields are set on the instance instead of the constructor's prototype, so you can't use super to access the instance field of a superclass." So what, specifically, is the issue you're pointing out to me?

My answer comes from implementations using "virtual method tables" (VMT), though things may be different nowadays, but I hope it is illustrative...
Your abstract class has no implementation of execute... that's a reason we use abstract classes or interfaces in the first place.
So if a runtime were setting aside "space" in memory for the method pointers of that class, each concrete method would point to an implementation... but the abstract one doesn't go anywhere.
Then your subclass comes along and provides an implementation for "execute". To facilitate polymorphism, its virtual method table (VMT) includes that of its parent... so all the concrete methods of Abstract still point somewhere.
Concrete can override any of those methods, and it also must provide the implementation of the inherited abstract method.
All of the methods available to the "Concrete class":
Abstract::constructor -> empty implementation
Abstract::execute -> points "nowhere"
Concrete::constructor -> points to its own impl that call super
Concrete::execute -> points to its own impl but CANNOT call super

The concrete class cannot call super to an abstract method because it doesn't point to any code... years ago in C or Object Pascal it would probably be null, but I do not know if that is how things happen under the covers today... the concept is the same though.
In the Concrete class, you typically want to invoke super when you want the inherited behavior, and trust polymorphism to find the right method pointer in the VMT in other cases.
Consider you are already trusting this concept when your service Impl class implements the "do" method of its interface... but you do not call super from the Impl class. Inside Concrete::execute you trust polymorphism, and inside the service Impl, you would not call super... knowing that it does not exist except "as an entry in the VMT that doesn't point anywhere".
Calling Service::do is totally valid on a concrete implementation... in fact, that is the whole idea. Service::do is a signature that gets inherited without any implementation. Your Concrete class is no different when it "inherits" a signature without an implementation.

To access protected members of a class you may to use the keyword this as shown in the TypeScript documentation.
Also as stated in the documentation:

A derived class can also override a base class field or property. You
can use the super. syntax to access base class methods. Note that
because JavaScript classes are a simple lookup object, there is no
notion of a “super field”.


This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question as asked.  Furthermore it is not true; you can access a protected member with super, as long as that member exists on the prototype. See this playground link for an example.

@jcalz thanks, I tried to expand the answer.
